# Invalid grant type passed - STK request

Tags: mpesa

I keep getting this error every time I try to make an STK push

"requestId" => "6255-20728117-1"
  "errorCode" => "400.008.02"
  "errorMessage" => "Invalid grant type passed"

Answer (score 3):

Check the url you are using and add the grant_type and ensure that the grant_type is associated with a customer_key as well as a customer_secret in the final post request
e.g
curl -X GET https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oaut/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials
As opposed to:
curl -X GET https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate

sample code snippet is as follows

```
consumer_key = keys.consumer_key
consumer_secret =keys.consumer_secret
api_URL = (
    "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials"
    )
r = requests.get(api_URL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret))
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a `grant_type` in your request. Check the Mpesa Api Documentation.